# Hibernate Inconsistency With MySQL Insert Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, netbeans, jakarta-ee

This problem is driving me insane. Basically, I have setup a hibernate mapping to a java class. The class will do insert to a table. But that is not happening. At the beginning, I am getting Hibernate locked due to timeout. Secondly it worked and then it didnt work.

For your information, I am using netbeans 6.9.1 and Hibernate 3 that came with it. And..the most weird thing is, when I ran the program in the debug mode, (where u put breakpoints, and the program crawl slowly from line to line) I can conclude that it takes around 5 second JUST to initialize the sessionFactory. Probably that is the main reason of the locked up.

What did I do wrong? Fyi, I am using LAMPP for mysql in the localhost.

Here is the Hibernate Configuration XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/rainbow</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And here is the mapping xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="datamap.Course" table="app_crs_info">
      <id name="id" column="ID" type="string"/>
      <property name="courseName" type="string">
          <column name="COURSE_NAME"/>
      </property>
      <property name="description" type="string">
          <column name="DESCRIPTION"/>
      </property>
      <property name="level" type="integer">
          <column name="LEVEL"/>
      </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is the mapped class:

```
public class Course {
    private String id;
    private String courseName;
    private String description;
    private int level;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the courseName
     */
    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    /**
     * @param courseName the courseName to set
     */
    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the description
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * @param description the description to set
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * @return the level
     */
    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    /**
     * @param level the level to set
     */
    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }
}
```

And this is how I called it:

```
public void registerCourse(String id, String description,
                                String name, String level) {
       session = null;
       crashLog = new CrashLog();


        try {

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            //session.getTransaction().begin();

            Course course = new Course();
            course.setId(id);
            course.setCourseName(name);
            course.setDescription(description);
            course.setLevel(Integer.parseInt(level));
            session.save(course);
            //session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            crashLog.writeToLog(CourseData.class.getName() + "Error : " + ex.toString());
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }


    }
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: can you connect to mysql well outside of hibernate?  have you tried enabling the hibernate sql logs to see what it is executing?  have you tried monitoring the mysql queries?

Comment: yes I can. In fact, in the same project, there are pages that connect using normal, painful JDBC programming. Those pages are working fine and fast. But when it came to the page that uses hibernate..this happened... I m so clueless...

Comment: Jtahlborn: How can I enable and see hibernate sql logs?

Comment: top hit from google: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t44119.html

Comment: INFO: Hibernate: insert into app_crs_info (COURSE_NAME, DESCRIPTION, LEVEL, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?). that is what the log said. That is weird, when I do debugging, the parameter is being parsed correctly (ie. the course member variable is set accordingly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly , you uncomment the source to do the transaction demarcation , so there are no transaction defined inside in your code . Please uncomment the line `session.getTransaction().begin();` and  `session.getTransaction().commit();`

Moreover , there is no point to do flush() in your finally block . Flushing but never commit after that means all your changes made during flushing will not be saved to the database. The flushing behavior can be control using `session.setFlushMode()`. By default , it is `FlushMode.AUTO`, which hibernate will automatically do flushing when a transaction is committed (`session.getTransaction().commit();`) , so you can remove the line `session.flush();`

Furthermore, one `SessionFactory` should represent one database .Creating a `SessionFactory` is expensive , but creating a `session` is  extremely inexpensive. So you should create one `SessionFactory` instance and use this single `SessionFactory`  to create all `Session` throughout your application.

Netbean 's built-in hibernate tool can create  a utility class to get a single `SessionFactory` instance. Please refer to `Creating the HibernateUtil.java Helper File` at  http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html

[image]

`

Comment: Thanks for info. I noticed that Hibernate takes alot of time to instantiate the sessionFactory. Is there any way that I can generate it during the web application load for the first time? For example in .NET i could instantiate it at Page_Load of index.htm